# Change key on array_chunk php

Tags: php, arrays

I have array based POST like this :

```
Array
(
[condition] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[container] => 
[cleaning] => Y
[owner] => Eagletainer
[last_cargo] => 1
[vessel] => 
[insulation] => 1
[tare] => 
[gross] => 
[capacity] => 
[unit_type] => IMO 1
[date_of_manu] => 
[name_manu] => 
[last25] => 
[cert25] => 
[last5] => 
[cert5] => 
[list2_item_0] => 1
[list2_kondisi_0] => 9
[list3_item_0] => 15
[list3_kondisi_0] => 3
[comments] => 
)
```

My case is, I want to chunk a lot of those element array into another array for insert_batch in my database.
This is the php code to chunk those array:

```
public function get_partition($array, $p, $c) {
    $partition = array_slice($array, $p);
    array_pop($partition);
    return $chunk = array_chunk($partition, $c);
}
```

Now, use it,

```
$detail = $this->get_partition($this->input->post(), 17, 2);
```

The result is :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 9
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 15
        [1] => 3
    )

)
```

My question in, how to change the key [0] and [1] into another key like [ID] and [CODE_DAMAGE]

I want them looked like this :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 1
        [CODE_DAMAGE] => 9
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 15
        [CODE_DAMAGE] => 3
    )

 )
```

Comment: re-loop the final result and make a associated array of it will make your problem solve...

Answer (score 1):

Re-loop the array and achieve your desired result like this:

```
$detail = $this->get_partition($this->input->post(), 17, 2);
$new_array = array();
$count = 0;
foreach($detail as $row){
   $new_array[$count]['ID'] = $row[0];
   $new_array[$count++]['CODE_DAMAGE'] = $row[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the indexes were already correct you could pass the optional third parameter: http://php.net/array_chunk

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => array(0 => 123, 1 => 1234), 1 => array(0 => 123, 1 => 1234));
$updatedArray = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $updatedArray[$k]['ID'] = $v[0];
    $updatedArray[$k]['CODE_DAMAGE'] = $v[1];
}
?>
```

Try this, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($detail as $key => $value){
    if($key == 0){
        $detail['ID'] = $value;
        unset($detail[$key]);
    }
    if($key == 1){
        $detail['CODE_DAMAGE'] = $value;
        unset($detail[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an example add your array to this code..it will work fine

```
$main = Array(Array(1,9),Array(15,3));
$b = array('ID', 'CODE_DAMAGE');
$new_array = array();
foreach($main as $subarray)
{
    $new_array[] = array_combine($b, $subarray);        
}
echo'<pre>';print_r($new_array);
```